# if(!IsPostback) doesn't exist in the current context

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm building a web application using a webform and I'm trying to store a counter in a Session, but I'm getting the error that   if(!IsPostback) doesn't exist in the current context. Can anyone help me with this issue?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if(!IsPostback)
{
Session["AttemptCount"] = 0;
}

}

  protected void submitAnswerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        //difficultyList.SelectedIndex = 2;
        answerStatus.Visible = true;


        int answer = randomNumber1 + randomNumber2;
        int counter = (int)Session["AttemptCount"];
        if (mathAnswerTextBox.Text == answer.ToString())
        {
  counter++;
            Session["AttemptCount"] = counter;

            answerStatus.Text = "Correct!";


           // scoreLabel.Text = "Score: " + counter.ToString();
            randomNumber1 = random.Next(0, 50);
            randomNumber2 = random.Next(0, 50);
            num1Label.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber1);//add this line 
            num2Label.Text = Convert.ToString(randomNumber2); //and this line
            num1Label.Visible = true;
            num2Label.Visible = true;
            mathAnswerTextBox.Visible = true;

            submitAnswerButton.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (mathAnswerTextBox.Text != answer.ToString())
        {

            answerStatus.Text = "Incorrect";

            incorrectStrikes.Text = counter.ToString();
            num1Label.Visible = true;
            num2Label.Visible = true;
            mathAnswerTextBox.Visible = true;
            submitAnswerButton.Visible = true;
        //    scoreLabel.Text = counterArray[0].ToString();

        }
```

Comment: IsPostBack has a lover case b in your example code. C# is case sensitive and it should be IsPostBack with a capital B.

Comment: Thank you for that. That did the trick, but I have one more question. My "counter" won't increment onclick. Do you know why? I updated the code above to show you the code,which is inside a button.

Comment: @user3880824 You need to increment your counter before you assign it back to the session, not after.

Comment: Ok I changed my code to put the counter incrementing above where it is being assigned to session, but this is still an issue?? Updated code above too.

Comment: do you know IntelliSense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I previously mentioned in my comment to your question, your original problem was with the lowercase **b** in Postback.  The reason your "AttemptCount" session variable is not being incremented is because your if statement only increments it:

```
if (mathAnswerTextBox.Text == answer.ToString())
```

I think you want to do this in the else clause of your if statement, and not when the answer is correct.

Comment: Thank You. That was the problem